# Simple search engine in Django. Search in html content

Tags: django

How to create simple search engine? 
I have something like this:

```
def search(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['search']
        if len(term) > 3:
            d = Data.objects.filter(Q(content__contains=term) | Q(
                desc__contains=term))
            count = d.count()
            return render_to_response('search_result.html', {'d': d, 'count': count}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('search_result.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is ok if I search in model but I need search in html content (I use django-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

Django chunks data is [stored](https://github.com/clintecker/django-chunks/blob/master/chunks/models.py.%20You%20can%20import%20it%20and%20query%20it.) in a model too. You can import it and filter it like any other model

```
class Chunk(models.Model):
    """
    A Chunk is a piece of content associated
    with a unique key that can be inserted into
    any template with the use of a special template
    tag
    """
    key = models.CharField(_(u'Key'), help_text=_(u"A unique name for this chunk of content"), blank=False, max_length=255, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(_(u'Content'), blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(_(u'Description'), blank=True, max_length=64, help_text=_(u"Short Description"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u'chunk')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'chunks')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.key,)
```

`contains` is an ok way to query if you have an extremely small dataset.  It just issues a `LIKE` query, so it will not scale very well. If you are going to have a significant amount of data it will be a good idea to look for an engine that was created specifically for full text searching.